# Validating whether a textbox contains only numbers

Tags: c#, mysql, exception, try-catch

So I have an idea, because i find it hard to make a code for txtbox that will only allow integer and not a letters in mysql using c#. My Plan is why not set the database column into integer instead of typical varchar and if ever you put a letter of course it will turn and exception so in that case I want to catch the exception and prompt a messagebox saying "Please enter only integer". What do you think?

Comment: You don't need to duplicate tags in title (especially in form of question "I'm using C#?" as if you don't know what language you use). Side note: your actual question seems to be "how to validate if string is integer to store in DB"...

Comment: Ok I'll rephrase it but that is what I intended to ask.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It's a good idea to use the correct column datatype for what you plan to store in it, but it's very easy to check whether a string contains only numbers - just parse and see if an error is returned:

```
int parsedValue;
if (!int.TryParse(textBox.Text, out parsedValue))
{
    MessageBox.Show("This is a number only field");
    return;
}

// Save parsedValue into the database
```

Comment: your code is new to me because I tried before different codes but they are not working. But anyway, I will try yours. Thank you

Comment: In addition to these checks, I'd still recommend changing your column to an integer column - better for data integrity, efficiency, and disk space...

Answer (score 4):

Visual studio has built in support for this (and you may also achieve it via coding). Here's what you need to do:

- Switch to design view from markup view.
- Now click on design view and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>.
- From the toolbox that opens click on Validation and drag a compare validator near your `TextBox`.
- Right click on the compare validator and choose properties, now locate `ErrorMessage` and write "Alert: Type only Number".
- In Control to Validate choose your control.
- In the Operator choose DataTypeCheck  and in the Type choose Integer.

Also via coding you can get it as:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int i;
    if (!int.TryParse(textBox.Text, out i))
    {
        Label.Text = "This is a number only field";
        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(Int32.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out int value))
{
    // Here comes the code if numeric
}
else
{
    // Here comes the code if not numeric
}
```

Comment: Please add some description to the TryParse function. Not only a code block

Comment: Just what I was looking for, and works as expected. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it this way

```
   int outParse;

   // Check if the point entered is numeric or not
   if (Int32.TryParse(propertyPriceTextBox.Text, out outParse) && outParse)
    {
       // Do what you want to do if numeric
    }
   else
    {
       // Do what you want to do if not numeric
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't even compile. You can't use boolean operators with integers (`&& outParse`).